# From where can I purchase a pet white mouse?

Tags: adoption, mice

Where is the best place to get a white mouse online?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'd probably have the best luck at a pet store, unless you happen to have a friend that breeds them (or a local breeder). However, if you go to the pet store, make sure they know you want *a* pet and not *food* for another :) While feeder mice are cute, cuddly, white, and everything else you are looking for - they're specifically bred for food and sometimes not under the best of conditions.

Domesticated mice tend to be a bit bigger, live longer and have been handled properly since breeding - making them a bit more naturally curious around humans and less likely to bite if frightened.

I recommend buying them in pairs, and getting a habitat large enough for the two of them to run around. Wheels, tubes and other accessories help to keep them active which leads to longer life.

Answer (score 7):

Most pet stores sell white mice for both pet and reptile feeder purposes.  Choose one for pet purposes, as feeder mice are intended for food and are potentially genetically inferior, possibly due to inbreeding.

That having been said, using a rescued feeder mouse with a potentially short life-span could be a good training tool to familiarize oneself with mouse pet care.  Unfortunately for the feeder mouse, I suspect the monetary investment difference between feeder-intended and pet-intended mice is negligible; therefore, you're better off selecting a pet-intended mouse.

Comment: Could also be an inexpensive (in time and money) way to see how well a child would actually take care of a pet, while giving a feeder mouse a great (albeit short) life. Provided of course that the mouse didn't pose any health risks, and nobody in the house objects to such a critter. The last pet albino I purchased was upwards of $20 for context and lived quite a while. That's a bit of an investment on both ends if you're worried that your child might quickly forget about the pet once the novelty is gone.

Comment: I once had white mice as pets, which may have been feeder mice for all I knew.  They apparently killed each other in a massive fight, according to my parents.

Comment: @JoshDM That seems suspicious that the last two would slay each other.  You might want to break out the truth serum for your parents.

Comment: @Oldcat - I think one killed the other, but the other mortally wounded the killer.